# How can an incrementally synchronized language server know, whether it missed a change?

Tags: language-server-protocol

LSP allows for synchronization (`textDocument/didChange`) to be *incremental*, as long as client and server support this.

Implementing support for this on the server's side, I am confused how the server is supposed to correctly order[^1] these incremental edits.
The server gets `DidChangeTextDocumentParams` containing `VersionedTextDocumentIdentifier` with a `version` field, that is [documented](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/lsp/3.17/specification/#versionedTextDocumentIdentifier) as follows (emphasis: mine):

> [...] The version number of a document will increase after each change, including undo/redo. **The number doesn't need to be consecutive**.

If it can be non-consecutive, then how can the server find out if it has missed a change?

In this context, I have also wondered, if there is any way to request a full synchronization of a document from the client, when the server suspects it is out of sync?
This would mitigate the issue, at least.

[^1]: most of the time they're received in the right order of course, and my implementation does work fine

Comment: The server has access to the document being modified, wouldn't be enough to access the file an do a read&update of the internal model when it suspects it is out of sync?

Comment: @AlejandroGonzález That would not be enough, as most language servers deal with intermediate document state as well (before the document is explicitly saved). Now that I'm thinking about this I imagine it might be a good first step to wait for a write notification and then do what you propose, at which point the server _ought_ to be up to date again.